# Consuming OData with Google Glass

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-glass, google-gdk, odata4j

I'm trying to consume OData within a Google Glass application. What I was doing so far is to import the required odata4j.JARs and implement a class called "PersonRequest" which extends the "AsyncTask" class. The class only does the following:

```
public class PersonRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Person>>{
 private ArrayList<Person> persons;
 @Override
 protected ArrayList<Person> doInBackground(Void... params){
    int i = 0;
    String serviceURL = "http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/";
    ODataConsumer myConsumer = ODataConsumers.create(serviceURL);
    for(OEntity category : myConsumer.getEntities("Categories").execute()){
     String categoryName = category.getProperty("Name", String.class).getValue();
     System.out.println("Category: " + categoryName);
    }
    return(this.persons);
 }
```

I call this class when I switch from one view to another by the following code:

```
new PersonRequest().execute()
```

The problem that I have right now is that I always get an error which says the following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ODataVersion 3.0
```

I've actually downloaded the latest OData-Package-Version 0.7 from the official odata4j website and added "odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle.jar" to it but this seems not to work...
Does anybody known how I can solve my problem???
Looking forward to your answers!

Greetings
Stef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found finally the solution ;) 
The problem is really caused by the ODataVersion... somehow it is not possible to consume data which comes from versions higher than 2.0!

Greetings